# Custom control properties not reflecting in ASPX markup

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, custom-controls, csproj

I'm having a .NET 4.0 solution with several projects inside it.

One project has all the custom controls implemented (say `CustomControlProject`).

The other project has the ASPX pages. (say `WebPagesProject`)

One of my custom control is a search textbox which has certain properties.

When I add a new property to it and build the entire colution, still that property doesn't appears in the intellisense in the ASPX page.

I checked the DLL reference it is taking the exact DLL from the `CustomControlProject`.

It is not hitting the break point when I attach my custom control code to the w3wp.exe process. My ASPX pages are hosted in (local) IIS.

I tried deleting the entire stuffs in the bin of custom control and build it, tried deleting DLLs from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET.. Temporary Internet files.

Checked the version of both the projects, it is same:

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

The only difference I found in both project files is this:

```
<OldToolsVersion>3.5</OldToolsVersion> (for custom control project)

<OldToolsVersion>4.0</OldToolsVersion> (for ASPX pages project)
```

The error which I'm getting

**Message: Cannot create an object of type 'CustomControlsProject.Interface.SearchTextBoxModeEnum' from its string representation 'forms' for the 'SearchTextBoxMode' property.**

The code:

```
 public enum SearchTextBoxModeEnum
    {
        global,
        forms,        
        account
    }

[Category("Seach Mode"),
DefaultValue(SearchTextBoxModeEnum.global),
Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared),
WebBrowsable(true),
WebDisplayName("SearchTextBoxMode"),
WebDescription("SearchTextBoxMode")]
public SearchTextBoxModeEnum SearchTextBoxMode
 {
                set;
                get;
 }
```

I added the last one (account). I can see the first two properties in the intellisense.

Can any one tell me what mistake I'm making ?

Comment: Please post the code for the new property you added -the reason it's not showing up in Intellisense is because the project isn't building because there's a syntax error on the property.

Comment: Thanks Micheal. Project is getting build successfully. Added the code.

Comment: Please post the code for the new property you created -the `enum` looks fine -it's saying the problem is with `SearchTextBoxMode`, not `SearchTextBoxModeEnum`.

Comment: I just added `account` in that SearchTextBoxEnum property. I'm adding that property where I defined it.

Comment: OK, so it's not the property declaration itself. Are you setting this property somewhere (e.g. `o.SearchTextBoxMode = "forms";`) anywhere in the code?